# Python - Date coming from SQL as a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to get a date from a table in SQL server but it returns as a list. How can I convert this back into datetime value?

Here's how I'm getting the date:

```
max_date = engine.connect().execute('select max(receive_datetime) from my_db.dbo.file_table').fetchall()
```

Here is what that outputs:

```
>>>[(datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 16, 18, 23),)]
```

How can I go about converting this to a date with ease? And more importantly am I getting it the wrong way that it comes out as a list?
I tried converting this with datetime.strptime but that expects a string and not a list.

Comment: Please clarify: what is your expected output? A datetime object? How many elements does the list have?

Comment: Try calling `.scalar()` instead of `.fetchall()`

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson. Adding `.scalar()` resolved my issue and the value is now coming in as datetime instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved**

I needed to replace `.fetchall()` with `.scalar()`

`max_date = engine.connect().execute('select max(receive_datetime) from my_db.dbo.file_table').scalar()`

and now the output is datetime instead of a list:

`>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 30, 16, 18, 23)`